# Firebase AppCheck with half of invalid requests

Tags: firebase-app-check

I have two apps (one Android and one IOS) that access the same firebase real-time database and I configured AppCheck in both apps and configured it as instructed, but almost half of the requests are returning as invalid.

Could anyone tell me how I can find out which app is causing this problem and what is the reason? Is there a more specific filter than the one shown below?

[image]

Comment: I had a similar issue - posted my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77752616/how-to-get-firebase-app-check-status-on-device) - looking into it a bit more, it looks like I am hitting my 10,000 call quota in the Play Integrity API and then further requests that day are marked as invalid. Go check if you are hitting that limit.