# How to get Firebase App Check status on device?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-app-check

I am using Firebase App Check in an existing multiplatform app. On the Android side I am using [Play Integrity](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/play-integrity-provider):

```kotlin
Firebase.appCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        DebugAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance()
    } else {
        PlayIntegrityAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance()
    }
)
```

and on the iOS side I am use [App Attest](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/app-attest-provider):

```swift
#if DEBUG
let providerFactory = AppCheckDebugProviderFactory()
AppCheck.setAppCheckProviderFactory(providerFactory)
#else
let providerFactory = SimpleAppCheckProviderFactory()
AppCheck.setAppCheckProviderFactory(providerFactory)
#endif

FirebaseApp.configure()
```

```swift
class SimpleAppCheckProviderFactory: NSObject, AppCheckProviderFactory {
  func createProvider(with app: FirebaseApp) -> AppCheckProvider? {
    return AppAttestProvider(app: app)
  }
}
```

App Check is currently set to "Monitor" in Firebase since I do not want to lock out existing users yet. These implementations have both been deployed to production for while now, but I am seeing a large percent of calls reported as "Unverified: invalid requests" and would like to make sure those are not coming from my apps before enabling Enforcement.

I have searched the logs and haven't found any messages indicating success or failure of the app check calls. Removing the App Check setup code above doesn't appear to make any difference since it is not enforced yet.

**Is there a way to query Firebase from the device and return the App Check status, or enable some sort of "app check required" option on the app-side instead of globally for testing?**

Answer (score 1):

I was able to come up with a solution using a Firebase cloud function with [app check enforcement enabled](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/cloud-functions):

```js
exports.checkAppCheck = functions
    .runWith({
        enforceAppCheck: true
    })
    .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
        return 0;
    }
);
```

Then I could call it within the app and check for success.

```kotlin
// Android
Firebase.functions.getHttpsCallable("checkAppCheck").call()
    .addOnCompleteListener { result ->
        val appCheckIsWorking = result.isSuccessful
        // handle outcome
    }
```

```swift
// iOS
Functions.functions().httpsCallable("checkAppCheck").call() { (result,err) in
    let appCheckIsWorking = err == nil
    // handle outcome
}
```

When I remove the app check code, or don't put the debug token into Firebase, this function gives `appCheckIsWorking == false` as I expect. When I add the debug token, the function call succeeds and `appCheckIsWorking` is true.

**Edit**
Turns out I was hitting the 10k requests per day limit. After getting an increase in the quota from Google I now have >99% valid requests again.